# Single quotes meaning in MySQL (concat)?

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I am very new to SQL and MySQL and I was just looking about the Concat function. I saw an example like this: `SELECT LOWER(CONCAT(first_name,'',last_name))`

Why do they use the single quotes between the first and last name? What does it represent/mean?

Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: No space between? Copy-and-paste problem perhaps.

Comment: It would be to place a space between the first_name and the last_name Only I dont think you have a space between the 2 single quotes. So you dont get `FredBloggs` and you instead get `Fred Bloggs` So `SELECT LOWER(CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name))`

Answer (score 0):

Checking at [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), we can see that `CONCAT()` accepts an arbitrarily large list of string arguments and packs them together. Empty strings don't add anything to the mix, so it's essentially pointless.

Judging from column names, it could a typo, a copy+paste error, a display problem due to an unsupported or non-printable character, or an evolution of previous code like `CONCAT(first_name, '_', last_name)` that someone edited but didn't care to polish.